# 301 Redirect on a Rewritten URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to do a 301 redirect on a rewritten url through .htaccess with no luck. 301 redirects are working for pages that do not currently exist, but just not on actual pages. For example, the following works:

```
RewriteRule ^randomword$ http://www.url2.com [R=301,L]
```

But, this does not:

```
RewriteRule http://www.url.com/game http://www.url2.com/chip [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: I ended up using `Redirectmatch 301 /game http://www.url2.com/chip?`

Answer (score 0):

First perameter of RewriteRule directive  starts with a url path, not with Scheme and a hostname,

The correct Rule is :

```
RewriteRule ^game$ http://www.url2.com/chip [R=301,L]
```